# Java - Could not reserve enough space for object heap

Tags: java, memory, jvm, minecraft

This might be an odd question but since its java related I'll ask it here, I'm trying to play minecraft with a mod that is requering at least 2GB RAM but everytime i try to put 2048MB it shows:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

I'm using this codes I don't know if it will help anything -Xms2048m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128m.

The only way to make it work is to set the xms to 1024MB and that make sjava run out of memory, how can i set java to us emore memory, I'm using Win10 64-Bit, Java 8 121 64bit, I have 16GB Ram.
Help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with solving a programming problem. This should've been posted in the game's/mod's tech support forum. Even the minecraft tag used states that this question is off-topic as this is unrelated to creating/developing the mod, but rather on how to use it.

Comment: I know this is off-topic but I've been looking for so many time and nothing solved my problem that I needed to try in here.

Comment: Sorry, but not being able to find it elsewhere does not mean it's ok to post things that are off-topic in here... and this is especially true if you *already knew* it was off-topic before posting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to edit the Xms and Xmn to whatever size you want them to be. You won't get much benefit from allocating big amounts of RAM, it'll just release pressure from the CPU since it'll have to do less deallocating. Tell me if it works, and if it doesn't try to be more specific on what you're doing.

Comment: That is the problem I can't edit the Xms and Xmn to more then 1024, where I need at least 2048, if I put it it shows the error message in the title

Comment: figures out I can allocate 1400mb and that is all that I need, but I would like to know why I cant allocate more ....

Comment: You could accept my answer then ahah. It looks like that on some systems allocating too much RAM causes the JVM problems. I don't have any idea why, since if you're 100% sure that you have a 64 bit version of windows and you have more than 4GB of RAM available it should work...

Comment: Exactly all I see online is "download 64-bit Java" but that is what I have.... I'm so confused

Comment: And this is even more strange since for example in Minecraft I had basically the same line of code just with 4GB of RAM dedicated since years ago I used to have fun with shaders and mods.